# How to add custom code to Angular cli generated service worker

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, service-worker

I can generate and config the service worker (by config file) generated by angular cli without issues. However there seems no documentation on how to add custom code the ngsw-worker.js, since i would like to add functions like push notification, post message etc. Wonder to plug in to the ngsw-worker.js

Answer (score 13):

You just need to create your own service worker file.

**First, lets start by creating our own very basic service worker**.

```
//my-service-worker.js

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  console.log('notification clicked!')
});
```

**Awesome, now in your App module change the service worker registration**

```
//app.module.ts

ServiceWorkerModule.register('my-service-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

**You will also need to add your service worker to your assets in your angular.json file**

```
//angular.json

  "assets": {
  ...,
  "src/my-service-worker.js"
}
```

**Great! Now you are all set, but we just lost all of the stuff that the angular service worker provides! Hang on, we’re not finished yet. Go back to your custom service worker and change it up**

```
//my-service-worker.js

importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  console.log('notification clicked!')
});
```

All Right! Now we have everything working, the angular cli accepting push notifications, and we can add our own fluff to the notification events!

https://medium.com/@smarth55/extending-the-angular-cli-service-worker-44bfc205894c

Comment: the problem with this solution is  that it is not integrated with webpack

Answer (score 5):

You can subscribe to the messages in your app:

```
import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';

this.SwPush.messages.subscribe(message => {
    console.log('[App] Push message received', message)
}
```

Check out this article:
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-2-practice-3221471269a1

Comment: I can see that api is exposed the method, but what about the rest of the Service worker apis. How can we extend this pacakage

Comment: Seems like not everything is supported yet: There is an open feature request for Background sync: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22145  
postMessage has nothing to do with service-worker you use it independently

Comment: @Stef Chäser: Hoi Stef, any suggestions to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449020/angular6-service-worker-and-background-sync. How can I modify this file ngsw-worker.js (add some custom code) in an official way? Yes I can add some fancy build steps that concat some stuff to this file after build, but this feels not right.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with **Angular8** I've found a way to use the **worker-plugin** to compile custom ServiceWorker code:

Prerequisites:

- Angular8+
- Enable Service Workers in Angular (*"serviceWorker": true*, etc)
- Enable WebWorkers in Angular (*"webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.workers.json"*)

See: [Angular: Using TypeScript for Service Worker (ServiceWorkerModule)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238882/angular-using-typescript-for-service-worker-serviceworkermodule/59803735#59803735)

Comment: did that work for you??

Comment: few years later i needed to do this again in angular16. Still works with some minor adjustments.

Comment: Really?!.. are you able to post a same repo or stackbliz for this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've updated my linked answer with more detailled descriptions. Hope this helps too.

Comment: Massively appreciate that. I'll test it out tomorrow.