# Angular: Using TypeScript for Service Worker (ServiceWorkerModule)

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker, angular-service-worker

Is it possible to register a ServiceWorker written in TypeScript with `@angular/service-worker`?

currently registering a service worker looks like this in **app.module.ts**:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: environment.production
})
```

Is it somehow possible to register a `ngsw-worker.ts`?

At least this is possible with web workers in Angular:

```
const worker = new Worker('../my-worker.worker', {
      type: 'module'
    });
```

*my-worker.worker.ts*

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

import {someMethod} from './some-method';

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
  postMessage(response);
  someMethod();
});
```

Any help is appreciated - thanks

Comment: Browsers don't know TypeScript. TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, and that's what browsers download and execute: JavaScript code, not TypeScript code.

Comment: Yep, but Angular compiles those TS files to JS with webpack internally. Why not also for service workers as they already support for web workers?

Comment: AFAIR, this code is used to register *the* Angular service worker, written and provided by Angular. Why would you rewrite it?

Comment: I want to use methods (TS files) on the SW as well as on the main thread. My current approach is to bundle them in a separate build step and import them via ```importScripts('sw-bundle.js')```. My question is if there is a better way to do this, e.g. with the Angular compiler. It works fine for web workers (with the code above), I would love to use something similar for SW as well.

Comment: but you are right it looks like ```ServiceWorkerContainer.register``` is just called from the Angular module

Answer (score 7):

As a beginner with Angular/TypeScript/Javascript I've tried the same for a few days.
My intents were to use TypeScript as my main language to use it as an es5 transpiler, so I don't have to worry about:

- language versioning (es5, es2015, ...)
- bundling
- linting
- etc

And I think I've got a nice, yet weird solution with uses the worker-plugin, available starting with **Angular8**. Adjusted for **Angular16**.

First of all: you need to enable [webworkers in angular](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker) and [serviceworker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro).
The angular.json then contains

```
"build": {
 "options": {
    "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.workers.json",
    ...
  }
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "serviceWorker": true,
      "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note: This is only in production mode. Probably to keep browser/cache/install sideeffects away from ng serve.
Somehow I've also lost this configuration during an ng update.

### Example:

##### tsconfig.workers.json

Allowing all kinds of web-workers

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/workers",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

##### workers/service-worker.worker.ts

This is the example target code.

```
// Import angular serviceworker
importScripts("ngsw-worker.js");

// custom code
addEventListener("message", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

##### workers/service-worker-config.ts

Angular generates hashed names for its *.js output. We need to grab this name.

```
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";

export let generatedServiceWorkerUrl: string = null;
(function generateUrl(): void {
    // Override the real Worker with a stub
    // to return the filename, which will be generated/replaced by the worker-plugin.
    // @ts-ignore
    Worker = class WorkerStub {
        constructor(public stringUrl: string, public options?: WorkerOptions) {}
    };

    const worker = new Worker(new URL("./service-worker.worker", import.meta.url), { type: "module" }) as any;
    generatedServiceWorkerUrl = worker.stringUrl;
})();

export const serviceWorkerConfig = {
    enabled: environment.production,
    serviceWorkerUrl: generatedServiceWorkerUrl
};
```

##### app.module.ts

```
import { serviceWorkerConfig  } from "./workers/service-worker-config";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        [...],
        ServiceWorkerModule.register(serviceWorkerConfig.serviceWorkerUrl, { enabled: serviceWorkerConfig.enabled })
    ],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This works great! It allows both custom code _and_ it allows testing your service work via `ng serve`  An update for Angular 10, as is, in production the `generateUrl` function will get removed (apparently because it's not directly referenced).  Calling it directly solves it, for example make `generateUrl` return the URL and then save it in the config using `serviceWorkerUrl: generatedUrl()`.

Comment: @kdubb could you edit the answer so we have a compatible code for futures versions of Angular

Comment: @Kelon I couldn't make your solution work. I have the following `Error: The AngularCompilerPlugin was not found. The @ngtools/webpack loader requires the plugin.`

Comment: I'm not sure how this is ultimately supposed to work. The service worker is registered and it tries to start, but I end up with a startup error that the worker couldn't be installed. It's trying to find the worker at `http://localhost:4200/service-worker.worker`, the URL isn't being generated/replaced by the build process.

Comment: The url is generated by the angular build process, which tries to create all generated "new Worker" calls. That's the reason we'll override this real Browser-known class with a WorkerStub and fill it with a import of the real service-worker.
Angular builds this with a hashed version number, like '0.777f70d1e77a7777d346.worker.js'

Comment: Does this solution assume you have a generated worker available in say your src or app folder that you can mess around with when serving with ```ng serve```? Did you just copy your auto generated file from a dist folder into src or app and start there?

Comment: @vaindil did you solve this? i ahve the same problem. that serviceworker not found

Comment: doesn't work.. I got this error. `service worker registration failed with: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope`

Comment: Im using ur solutions but got 1 problem. When i want to register a real Web Worker. And the Worker class has been overrided how do i solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse it is possible to rewrite anything in js in typescript. But to run it in browser  you will have to compile it into JavaScript. As, browser doesn't interpret/understand  typescript as of now.

To do so, you can use typescript command: **tsc** .

In your package.json, create a script command like this:-

```
"scripts": {
    "compile-to-ts": "tsc my-service-worker.ts"
}
```

Now run above command as:-

```
npm run compile-to-ts
```

It will compile your typescript file into javascript and place the generated file in a directory based on tsconfig file.

**UPDATE:** You can also use type definition of service worker from  [here](https://gist.github.com/tiernan/11a40d253a55a5c5ff518d6deae3ee48) . You can utilize this to improve type safety in your service worker typescript code and avoid any typescript related error(if any).

Comment: Fair enough, but if my ```my-service-worker.ts``` is importing stuff from other ts file (like someMEthod above) a bundler like webpack or rollup is needed. This is a step I want to avoid to let the Angular compiler handle this