# Create Angular custom service worker

Tags: angular, typescript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I am developing an Angular PWA, where we need to download big files in the background for later processing.
We would like to trigger the downloads with push notifications, so when the user opens the application, the data is already present.
We managed to receive the the push notification even with closed browser, but unfortunately the service worker which is serving this is written in JS, and we would like to have it in typescript like the other parts of the project. So far I have not found anything helpful the service workers are always js files. Is there a way to do that in TS with Angular?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can check these answers here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238882/angular-using-typescript-for-service-worker-serviceworkermodule